# IK feet making knees misbehave and shins twist

Tags: rigging

I'm not to the point of using a mesh just yet - this is my blocky storyboarding person and the rig that came with Blender 3.0 (currently using 3.1 but problem came along for the ride). Looks fine in rest mode, but bones twist when I raise the foot, and the knee is def not going towards the pole target.[image]

Moving the foot along the Z axis shows off the issue.[image]

I can move the pole target to correct the knee position but this results in the shin-bone twisting.

I looked thru the other q/a sim to this but didn't see a clear answer on how to fix it. X/Y/Z coords seem to be right. What am I missing? I'm pretty new to Blender so assume I need guidance.

Comment: Are the knee joints bent forward slightly towords th pole target? If they're dead straight they might not bend forward towards the pole correctly.

Comment: They are. I used Royal Skies tutorial on this, he mentioned to bend the knees slightly forward.

Comment: You'll need to upload your blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ and put the link to it in your question so that someone can have a look. - I'm going to bed soon so someone else will have to look at it! :^)

Comment: I didn't realize Pasteall.org was a thing.  Here's the link.  https://pasteall.org/media/5/7/57fb532b842ac1288d8a494aa87e530d.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your knees are a bit bent on Y, I don't know if there's another way but to straighten the bones in *Edit* mode:

[image]

It will work fine:

[image]

Comment: I see. I made the thigh rig-bones follow the shape of the actual bones, but there's no reason they have to. If that's the root of my issue, it's an easy fix. Thanks!